# How to sum columns when table is joined?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum

Trying to sum from a table that is joined to another (resulting in multiple rows per row of the first table) it is counting the amount for *each* of the rows in second table.

Tables:

```
create table t_orders (
    oid int,
    cartlink nvarchar(3),
    ordertotal float,
    ordertax float
);
create table t_cart (
    cartlink nvarchar(3),
    productid int
);

insert into t_orders (oid,cartlink,ordertotal,ordertax) values
    (1,'abc',10, 2),
    (2,'cdf',9, 1),
    (3,'zxc',11, 3)
;
insert into t_cart (cartlink,productid) values
    ('abc', 123),('abc', 321),('abc', 987),
    ('cdf', 123),('cdf', 321),('cdf', 987),
    ('zxc', 123),('zxc', 321),('zxc', 987)
;
```

Using following values for `t_orders` table is more accurate to the problem.  Using `distinct` only counts order 2 and 3 once because both of their totals are 9.

```
insert into t_orders (oid,cartlink,ordertotal,ordertax) values
    (1,'abc',10, 2),
    (2,'cdf',9, 1),
    (3,'zxc',9, 3)
;
```

Query and result:

```
SELECT
    SUM(t_orders.ordertotal) AS SumOfTotal,
    SUM(t_orders.ordertax)   AS SumOfTax
FROM
    t_orders
JOIN t_cart ON t_orders.cartlink = t_cart.cartlink
;
```

| SumOfTotal | SumOfTax |
| --- | --- |
| 90 | 18 |

What I want :

| SumOfTotal | SumOfTax |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 6 |

I *have* to join `t_orders -> t_cart -> t_products -> t_manufacturer` because I'm trying to sum from `t_orders WHERE t_manufacturer.type = 'some value'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT t_orders.ordertotal) AS SumOfTotal
    , SUM(DISTINCT t_orders.ordertax) AS SumOfTax 
FROM t_orders
JOIN t_cart ON t_orders.cartlink = t_cart.cartlink
```

Comment: That works for my little test, but in the real db, the sums are about 20% of what they should be.  Does the 'distinct' look for all the 'ordertotal' values and only sum the unique ones? In other words if two orders have the total 9.99, it only counts one of them?

Comment: @doug, of course  if you add group by t_orders.cartlink

Comment: using group by gives me a row for every row, not just the 2 sums.

Answer (score -2):

> "… *I'm trying to sum from `t_orders WHERE t_manufacturer.type = 'some value'`.*"

Using sub-query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(t1.Total) AS SumOfTotal,
    SUM(t1.Tax)   AS SumOfTax
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(t_orders.ordertotal) AS Total,
            MAX(t_orders.ordertax)   AS Tax
        FROM t_orders
        JOIN t_cart         ON t_orders.cartlink         = t_cart.cartlink
        JOIN t_products     ON t_cart.productid          = t_products.pid
        JOIN t_manufacturer ON t_products.manufacturerid = t_manufacturer.mid
        WHERE t_manufacturer.type = 'some value'
        GROUP BY t_orders.oid
    ) AS t1
```

Or:

```
SELECT
    SUM(t1.Total) AS SumOfTotal,
    SUM(t1.Tax)   AS SumOfTax
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(t_orders.ordertotal) AS Total,
            MAX(t_orders.ordertax)   AS Tax
        FROM t_orders
        JOIN t_cart         ON t_orders.cartlink = t_cart.cartlink
        JOIN t_products     ON t_cart.productid  = t_products.pid
        WHERE t_products.manufacturerid IN (
            SELECT mid FROM t_manufacturer WHERE type = 'some value'
        ) AS t2
        GROUP BY t_orders.oid
    ) AS t1
```